# Modifying only one field with a twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type that has multiple fields.   I'm fine with the generic display view for all but one of those fields.   Is it possible to use a twig template to modify only one of those fields?

For example:

**Content type**: Stuff and Things
with **Fields**:
Body,
URL,
Notes,
Status,
Peer Review

I want to modify the URL field and leave the rest alone... is this doable, or do I have to render each field in the twig template?

Comment: you should get familiar with [overriding Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates). Make sure you have debugger on to know what you will be calling your overriding file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the field template instead of node. Enable [twig debugger](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) and then inspect element with browser to see all the template files available to use/override.

You'll see you can use `field--[field-name].html.twig` or `field--node--[field-name]--[content-type].html.twig` if you want to be more specific.